# How everyone manage their firestore paths?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am using cloud function and client access firestore.but all paths string are hardcode in code. once I changed a collection name I need to change everywhere that the code access same collection. Anyone have a better way to manage them?

Comment: Why would you change the collection name? This sounds like a design flaw. You should only change the content of a document, but never the path of a collection. The only operations on a collection should be adding or removing documents.

Comment: My project are still under developing.And I also want to prevent typing wrong string in code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of literal strings everywhere, declare a global constant. For example, the usual thing in Swift is a struct or enum with a constant static property.

```
struct Constants {
    static let key = "whatever"
}
```

Now you can say `Constants.key` anywhere in your program. Any computer language will have something equivalent.